# Android Architecture Component: How to insert repository parameter

Tags: android, android-architecture-components

In a viewmodel class, I've seen sample codes where the constructor takes in a repository as a parameter. Like so:

`public SampleViewModel(SampleRepository sampleRepository){
    ...
}`

But in the activity, you use this line to create a viewmodel class `ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(SampleViewModel.class)`. How do you pass a repository as a parameter to the viewmodel? I also come across mentioning of "dependency injection". Being an inexperience programmer, can anyone advice if DI is related to my question?

Comment: what `SampleRepository` do you mean? can you point to any code?

Comment: Yeah, I was following the sample code snippet on android developer site https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/guide.html. Under the "Connecting ViewModel and the repository" heading, the `UserProfileViewModel` constructor uses @Inject to inject the repository? But where the repository actually get constructed and passed in?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to supply a ViewModelProvider.Factory when you get your viewmodel.

```
ViewModelProviders.of(this, new SampleViewModelFactory(sampleRepo)).get(SampleViewModel.class)
```

Here's a sample:

```
class SampleViewModelFactory implements ViewModelProvider.Factory {

    private final SampleRepository repo;

    @Inject
    public SampleViewModelFactory(SampleRepository repo) {
       this.repo = repo;
    }

    @Override
    public SampleViewModel create(Class modelClass) {
        return new SampleViewModel(repo);
    }
}
```

Comment: if i create viewmodel with factory then call again with new parameter(SampleRepository ) , it will return new instance of viewmodel?

Comment: @Entreco How to return generic viewModel from `create()`?

Comment: @PallaviTapkir what do you mean with `generic`? Generic as in: "a ViewModel with a generic type such as `ViewModel<T>` "?

Comment: Yes. ViewModel with generic type like `<T : ViewModel?>`